# Adding a third level to treeview active x control using VBA in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following VBA code which populates a treeview control with the parent table `Groups` and then the child table `Categories`, I also have a child to `categories` named `Section`. I would like to be able to add a third level to my treeview control, so I can display `section`. However, I don't know how to do this correctly. Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use the same method of adding a child level as I have done with the `group` and `categories`; but unsuccessfully so far.

I am not sure if my original code is entirely correct, but it appears to work ok.

I am using Microsoft treeview control version 6.0, if that makes any difference.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim nodX As Node
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim MyRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyRSChild As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Prt_Group ORDER BY Group_Number", dbOpenDynaset)


Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add(, , , "Parts List Treeview")

'Populate grp Nodes
Do While Not MyRS.EOF
    Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add(1, tvwChild, "Group" & MyRS![PartGroupID], MyRS![Group_Number] & " - " & MyRS![Group_Description])
        nodX.EnsureVisible
    MyRS.MoveNext
 Loop

 strSQL = "Select * From Prt_Category ORDER BY PartCat_Number"
 Set MyRSChild = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

 'Populate category Nodes
 Do While Not MyRSChild.EOF
   Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add("Group" & MyRSChild![PartGroupID], tvwChild, "A" & CStr(MyRSChild![PartCatID]), _
              " " & MyRSChild![PartCat_Number] & " - " & _
              MyRSChild![PartCat_Description])
   MyRSChild.MoveNext
 Loop

 MyRSChild.Close
 MyRS.Close
 Set MyRSChild = Nothing
 Set MyRS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code that successfully works. I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way of coding this, but it does work. This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443386(v=vs.60).aspx) helped me understand the node object.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim nodX As Node
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim MyRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyRSChild As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Prt_Group ORDER BY Group_Number asc", dbOpenDynaset)


Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add(, , , "Groups/Categories/Sections Treeview")

'Populate grp Nodes
Do While Not MyRS.EOF
    Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add(1, tvwChild, "Group" & MyRS![PartGroupID], MyRS![Group_Number] & " - " & MyRS![Group_Description])
        nodX.EnsureVisible
    MyRS.MoveNext
 Loop

 strSQL = "Select * From Prt_Category ORDER BY PartCat_Number ASC"
 Set MyRSChild = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

 'Populate category Nodes
 Do While Not MyRSChild.EOF
   Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add("Group" & MyRSChild![PartGroupID], tvwChild, "A" & CStr(MyRSChild![PartCatID]), _
              " " & MyRSChild![PartCat_Number] & " - " & _
              MyRSChild![PartCat_Description])
   MyRSChild.MoveNext
 Loop
'-------------------NEW CODE FOR THIRD LEVEL----------------------------    
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim myRSChild1 As DAO.Recordset

strSQL1 = "Select * From Prt_Section ORDER BY Section_Number"
Set myRSChild1 = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL1, dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not myRSChild1.EOF
   Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add("A" & CStr(myRSChild1![PartCatID]), tvwChild, "B" & CStr(myRSChild1![SectionID]), _
              " " & myRSChild1![Section_Number] & " - " & _
              myRSChild1![Section_Description])
   myRSChild1.MoveNext
 Loop
'------------- END OF ADDITIONAL CODE-----------------------    
 'Root Text Bold
 Treeview1.Nodes(1).Bold = True


 MyRSChild.Close
 MyRS.Close
 myRSChild1.Close
 Set MyRSChild = Nothing
 Set MyRS = Nothing
 Set myRSChild1 = Nothing
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Having not enough information to provide a full answer I just can help you a little with this:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
     '.....
     'Populate category Nodes
     Do While Not MyRSChild.EOF
         Set nodX = Treeview1.Nodes.Add("Group" & MyRSChild![PartGroupID], tvwChild, "A" & CStr(MyRSChild![PartCatID]), _
              " " & MyRSChild![PartCat_Number] & " - " & _
              MyRSChild![PartCat_Description])

         'insert third level node begins here
         'Maybe do a dataset operation on "Section table" and a while loop
          Treeview1.Nodes.Add nodx, tvwChild, "KEYOFSECTION", "LABELOFSECTION"

         MyRSChild.MoveNext
     Loop
 '...

End Sub
```

Change "KEYOFSECTION" with a unique key and "LABELOFSECTION" with an appropriate Section label